# Including external JS File in Angular Project doesn't work like it is supposed to

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

so I have this strange behaviour where a Javascript File works for my /login Page but only when I'm on this specific page, not for the others.

So for **example** when I reload the Chrome Tab for the `/login` it works perfectly, the script file gets accepted. But when I go from `/login` to `/home` and back to `/login` it doesn't work anymore, the script file with my little animation won't run AND I get **no error**

My login.js file is in the assets/scripts folder and looks like this:

```
    if (window.location.pathname === '/login') {
  window.onload = function () {
    const sign_in_btn = document.getElementById("sign-in-btn");
    const sign_up_btn = document.getElementById("sign-up-btn");
    const container = document.querySelector(".containerLOGSIGN");

    sign_up_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      container.classList.add("sign-up-mode");
    });


    sign_in_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      container.classList.remove("sign-up-mode");
    });
  }
}
```

The `window.location.pathname` is to only execute script when on `/login` Page.
The `window.onload` is to avoid this error: *"uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null"*

I have linked the script path in my login component HTML at the end:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/scripts/login.js" ></script>
```

And in the angular.json config file:

```
"scripts": ["apps/mreza-mladih-platform/src/assets/scripts/login.js"]
```

Thanks for helping!

Greetings from Germany

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question.
I used [ngclass] and click listener on the html file to get the same result.